# Finding factor of 21181*2^28+1

Tags: number-theory, factoring

I am working to eliminate 21181 from the list of possible Sierpinski number?I m finding the converging set of factors for this number if it exist? Up to n=100 except n=28 , I can prove that 21181*2^n is a composite number.  But I don't have any medium  which can calculate the factor of that number?so please help me to know factors of number 21181*2^28+1.

Thank you so much

Comment: $13$ divides it https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%2821181+2%5E%2828%29%2B1%29

Comment: `Prelude Math.NumberTheory.Primes> factorise $ 21181*2^28 + 1
[(13,1),(633091,1),(690839,1)]
(0.06 secs, 0 bytes)`

Comment: $21181\times 2^{28}\equiv 4\times 2^{28}=2^{30}=(2^6)^5\equiv(-1)^5=-1\bmod 13$

Comment: The number is so small, that there are many ways to factor it, unless the task is to find a factor by hand. Factordb is a possibility, Wolfram Alpha, Magma Online Calculator or software-tools like PARI/GP.

Comment: $21181\cdot 2^n$ is trivially composite for $n>0$. Do you mean "$21181\cdot 2^n+1$" ?

Comment: @Peter thanks actually i was using google calculator and for that it was a big number so sorry.Now i m using wolfram alpha.